# Create a coupon on specific category in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, free-shipping

I am working on magento 1.9.1.

I am offering free shipping if customer chooses a product from particular category (Say Category B).

In the cart page, the customer have added other category products too.

Ex:

```
Product 1 - Category A, Product 2 - Category C, Product 3 - Category B
```

Now, the coupon must not apply if Other category products are added (Say Category A & C).

Is there a method for this to happen?

Comment: Can you please tell me ,Can product2 is included in Category A?

Comment: No. Its not included

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in Magento.

**Steps**

1. Go to `Promotion > Shopping cart price rule` and add new.
2. Give name and other info in **Information Block** and go to "Condition Block**
3. Now, click on **"+" image**, and select "Product Attribute Combinations" from dropdown.
4. Then, again click on **"+" image** inside that and this time select "Category" from dropdown and choose any category you want.

Now, go to **Actions** block and set following:

5. `Discount Amount` to **`0`**.
6. `Apply to Shipping Amount` to `Yes`.
7. `Free Shipping` to `For matching items only`.
8. **Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)** section, again click on **+ image** and select **Category** from dropdown and also choose that category again.

This should enable what you are looking for.

Comment: How can i exclude 5 specific categories? Actually discount applied for all products, i need discount not apllied to selected 5 categories.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about 100%,But it may be help  my solution

Hi you can do this by Shipping Cart rules.

**Step1:** Goto admin>Promotion>Shopping cart rules

**Step2:** Create Shopping Cart rules

**Step3:** On this Action tab put logic shopping  and here magento is provide to item wise discount match on `Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions`

**Need  to set Further rules processing yes thus other coupon cannot apply**

See the Screen shot:
[image]

Study:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes

Comment: I tried but coupon is applied even if there are another category product. I dont want the coupon code to apply if other category is included

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to admin panel magento
2. Hover on Promotions
3. Shopping cart price rules
4. Click add new Rule
5. fill the required details according to the requirement like Rule name, decsription,status etc
6. Click on conditions tab
7. [image: This is the condition I made]
8. One condition of "**an item is FOUND**"
   and second condition of "**an item is NOT FOUND**"
9. [image: Click on add button to make new condition]
   Click on add button to make new condition
10. From the select option select "**product attribute combination**"
11. Again click on Add image button to define the condition
12. Select category from **product attribute**
13. And define the category for which you are making the coupon for
14. Then again as shown in screenshot make second condition for **an item is NOT FOUND**
15. And define those categories from which if you add a product then discount coupon should become invalid.

Thank You!!!
**Do let me know if any doubt...**